# Confusing rewrite rule: Need help!

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need a rewrite rule that will do an internal redirect from:
`<domain>/directory/<anything>/<anything>.php` to:
`<domain>/directory/<anything>.php` with `<anything>` passed as a parameter, and it needs to leave all other parameters alone.

I get headaches from mod_rewrite. My issue is `<anything>.php`, I cannot find any examples for anything like that.

Example:  domain.com/directory/something/lol.php?param=value ought to internally redirect to domain.com/directory/lol.php?param=value&someotherparam=something

Thanks for the help! I have read through many tutorial sites, but I am in the dark here...

EDIT: Code tags added since it wasnt showing up properly >.>

Not all pages will have other parameters passed, some might have only one, some might have many. This is another bit that confuses me...

Comment: This is a programming question, I would hardly say it belongs on serverfault. Whoever voted to close this clearly has no idea what mod_rewrite is....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^directory/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.php$ directory/$2.php?someotherparam=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will redirect `domain.com/directory/something/lol.php?param=value` to `domain.com/directory/lol.php?param=value&someotherparam=something`, as requested. (I'll note that currently, none of the other replies do so.)

Comment: Deleted my answer. Zarel's regex is better. +1

Comment: Okay, so if I put it into the .htaccess of my subdomain it will continue to work? Do I need to change the base?

Comment: Aha, issue found! How can I make this work when accessing the page from /directory/lol without a page?

Comment: Well, what do you want `/directory/lol` to load? `/directory/lol.php`? `/directory/index.php?param=lol`?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^rewrite/(.+)/lol.php$ rewrite/lol.php?someotherparam=$1 [QSA,R,L]
```

Comment: Wouldn't [R] force an external redirect in this case?